# How do I make Pinterest pin it button work with HTML5 picture srcset?

Tags: html, image, pinterest

I have a basic custom Pin it button. This picks up images inline to the page, but it's not picking up images using the HTML5 picture element with srcset.

```
<a href="//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/" data-pin-do="buttonBookmark" data-pin-color="red" data-pin-height="28"><img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pinit_fg_en_rect_red_28.png" /></a>
```

Here's an example of the picture element in use, where the button is **not** working:

```
<picture>
  <img srcset="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/652/coffee5.jpg">
</picture>
```

A very stripped down demo to play with that illustrates the problem: http://codepen.io/michaelpumo/pen/eZyddp

Any ideas?

**Update**: I might actually have to add that my usecase is a bit more complicated than this. The above is a simplified / stripped down version to illustrate the point. I'm lazy loading these too you see.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following. It works.

```
<picture>
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/652/coffee5.jpg" srcset="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/652/coffee5.jpg" data-pin-description="Hello World">
</picture>
```

I thought src and description should be there for Pinterest.

Comment: Cannot do this, because I'm actually lazy loading images too. If I set the src attribute, this image is downloaded regardless.